# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 15201 (GC)

Tags: android, garbage-collection, fatal-error

I have been getting this error since last three days, I did a lot of search but I dint find any useful answer, (some people say that it is bcoz of null referencing but I am no where referencing null) I am getting this error when I am trying to write the inputstream of an image file into the byte array, any help will be appreciated

Logcat show like this:

```
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5178K, 21% free 45743K/57384K, paused 49ms, total 50ms
Grow heap (frag case) to 68.666MB for 22220109-byte allocation
GC_CONCURRENT freed 41K, 15% free 67405K/79084K, paused 3ms+11ms, total 60ms
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 21864 (GC)
```

Answer (score 0):

`GC_FOR_ALLOC` means there were not enough free memory to fulfill an allocation request, so a garbage collection was necessary, whereas `GC_CONCURRENT` just means that the GC felt like running, typically because the amount of free memory became lower than a certain threshold after an allocation.

You can try to analyze memory for your Android application:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/traceview.html
http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html

Check your app for memleaks

Comment: Analyze your code with `traceview` tool for `memleaks`. Not proper streaming and bytes array using can cause memleaks

Comment: I am a new-bee in android I am unable to find where the leaks are though I use MAT, I am getting this fatal signal when I use byte array to load image file

Comment: I dont know what exactly causing this problem is it bcoz of GC? same code is running fine in Nexus 4 which is having kitkat OS version in it, plz help me out